# Select in php with the clause WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a quiz application and I need to retrieve "n" number of questions from a database. I also need to filter the result with categories or difficulties filters.

I don't have any problem if the user make a category choice (for example) :

```
$size = $_POST['param0'];
$category = $_POST['param1'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *
                      FROM questions_fr
                      WHERE categories = :categories
                      LIMIT 0, $size");

$stmt->bindparam(":category", $category);
$stmt->execute();
```

But what if he wants all the categories ?

Can I do something like that to make only one query in my php file ?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *
                      FROM questions_fr
                      WHERE categories = * (here, select all the categories)
                      LIMIT 0, $size");
```

Or should I do something like this ?

```
(pseudocode)
if ($category != "all_categories")
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *
                          FROM questions_fr
                          WHERE categories = :categories
                          LIMIT 0, $size");
}
else if ($category == "all_categories")
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *
                          FROM questions_fr
                          LIMIT 0, $size");
}
```

Comment: Yep, *generate* different queries according to the parameters passed

Comment: Watch out for `$size` as it is a gaping SQL injection security hazard.  Suggest you ensure it is a valid integer in the correct range first.

Comment: ( $category == 'all_categories') ? $stmt = "" : $stmt = "";
So much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they select 'all categories' set the category variable to a wildcard and use the `LIKE` clause.

```
if ($category == "all_categories") {
    $category = '%';
}

...

SELECT *
FROM questions_fr
WHERE categories LIKE :categories
LIMIT 0, $size
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another parameter.

```
SELECT *
  FROM questions_fr
  WHERE categories = :categories
    OR 1 = :all_categories
  LIMIT 0, $size
```

Then just pass it as `1` if you want all categories.

Comment: Why not make `$size` a placeholder too?

Comment: @JamWaffles: iirc in case of *real* placeholders it wouldn't work